# Why push elements into struct arrays Error

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, mist, dapp-development

```
contract MyContract {
struct Posposal{
    uint posposalId;//
    bytes1 description_;//
    uint userId;//
    uint amount;//
    address voteSponsorAddr;//

}
Posposal[] public curPosposals; //当前提议投票记录
uint public posposalNextId=0;// 标识投票建议递增  

function MyContract() {

}
uint public expId;
address public expTarget;
string public expDes;
function issuse(uint userId,address target_,uint amount_,string description_)  {
    expId=userId;
    expTarget=target_;
    expDes=description_;
    curPosposals.push(Posposal(posposalNextId,0x00,userId,amount_,msg.sender));//
    posposalNextId++;
}}
```

When I deploy this contract, and invoke function issue (`pass params 1,0x7812b816a427974Ca61d56c7a7CfAaa011bb2351,1000,"transfer 100"`), the transaction perform successfully. The variant `expId`,`expTarget`,`expDes` could get the right value, but `curPosposals[0]` is wrong? why?                                                                                  After several trials, when `move bytes1 description_;` to the last position, it works.

Comment: Your question is unclear: did the transaction succeed? Did you have enough gas? Did curProposals[0] have values? Were these values wrong?

Comment: I have tested your code in browser solidity and curProposals[0] returns the desired values; how are you testing this?

Comment: It could not return the desired values. when pass variants(1,0x7812b816a427974Ca61d56c7a7CfAaa011bb2351,1000,"transfer 100")      ,expId=1,expTarget=0x7812b816a427974Ca61d56c7a7CfAaa011bb2351,expDes=transfer 100, but curProposals[0] returns error values.